# NetworkX ノードのα値を連続的に変化させ、動画を作成したい

Tags: python, python3, networkx

以下のページを参考にノードの色のα値を変化させたものをGIFにしたいのですが、うまくいきません。

[Using NetworkX with matplotlib.ArtistAnimation - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229563/using-networkx-with-matplotlib-artistanimation)

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0,1),(1,2),(2,0)])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
pos= {0: (3, 3), 
        1: (2, 2), 2: (4, 2)}
nc = np.random.random(3)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos)
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos) 

def update(n):
    random.seed(1)
    nc = np.random.random(3) #ここがうまくいきません。
    nodes.set_array(nc) #ここの処理が？
    return nodes,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=50, blit=True)
```

例えば、縦がノード数、横がRGB+アルファ値の行列が与えられた場合、この４番目のアルファ値だけを時間ごとに変化させたいのです。

```
nc = [[0.13436424, 0.84743374, 0.76377462, 0.38538581],
      [0.25506903, 0.49543509, 0.44949106, 0.00395534],
      [0.65159297, 0.78872335, 0.09385959, 0.00395534]]
    nx.draw(G,pos,node_color=nc)
```

その場合、nodes.set_array(nc) の処理がよくわからないのですが、どのように書けば良いのでしょうかご教授願います。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アルファ値が時間経過とともにどのように変化するのかわからないのですが、ここではランダムに変化するものとしました。

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0,1),(1,2),(2,0)])
pos= {0:(3,3), 1:(2,2), 2:(4,2)}

nc = [[0.13436424, 0.84743374, 0.76377462, 0.38538581],
      [0.25506903, 0.49543509, 0.44949106, 0.00395534],
      [0.65159297, 0.78872335, 0.09385959, 0.00395534]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))

def update(n):
  ax.clear()
  nc[0][3] = np.random.random(1)[0]
  nc[1][3] = np.random.random(1)[0]
  nc[2][3] = np.random.random(1)[0]
  nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color=nc, ax=ax)
  edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=ax)

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=250)
#anim.save('animation.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！